# Return String in UTF-8 so it can be stored in a DB

Tags: java, encryption, utf-8

I´m implementing an encryption with "One time Pad" and the return is a string that my database doesn´t like

java.sql.SQLException: General error message from server: "Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x9C\xC2\x98u\xC2...'

```
    public String encrypt(String message, String key) {
            if (message.length() != key.length()) error("Lengths must be equal");
            int[] im = charArrayToInt(message.toCharArray());
            int[] ik = charArrayToInt(key.toCharArray());
            int[] data = new int[message.length()];

            for (int i=0;i<message.length();i++) {
                    data[i] = im[i] + ik[i];
            }

            return new String(intArrayToChar(data));
    }
     private int chartoInt(char c) {
            return (int) c;
    }

    private char intToChar(int i) {
            return (char) i;
    }

    private int[] charArrayToInt(char[] cc) {
            int[] ii = new int[cc.length];
            for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){
                    ii[i] = chartoInt(cc[i]);
            }
            return ii;
    }

    private char[] intArrayToChar(int[] ii) {
            char[] cc = new char[ii.length];
            for(int i=0;i<ii.length;i++){
                    cc[i] = intToChar(ii[i]);
            }
            return cc;
    }
```

How can i change the above code so that i can insert the output string into my Database 
**without changing the lenght of the string** ?

Comment: Bytes are not strings.  You should not use a string column.

Comment: One-time pads are almost never a good idea.

Comment: Column in DB is VARCHAR

Comment: VARCHAR is for strings.  You aren't dealing with strings.

Answer (score 0):

The String type is intended to be a representation of text.  The actual content of a String is a sequence of 16 bit values that represent text encoded as UTF-16 / UCS-2.  While UTF-16 is a sequence of 16 bit values, it is not *any* sequence of 16 bit values.  In particular there is a subrange of the 16-bit values that is reserved for representing code points that are greater or equal to 2<sup>16</sup>.  These values are used in pairs - called *surrogate pairs*.  If you have one of these characters and don't follow it with a second such character, the string is nor well-formed UTF-16 ... and cannot be transcoded to UTF-8.

Basically, your approach is incorrect.  An arbitrary sequence of `char` values cannot be converted to UTF-8 ... or indeed to any character set.

You have two choices:

- Store your "encrypted" in the database as a BLOB or a byte array (if supported).  In other words, change the database column type.
- Map your array of `char` values to an array of `byte`, and then encode the bytes using hexadecimal or base64 or some other robust binary-to-text encoding scheme.  This will (inevitably) make the "encrypted" strings longer than the original ones.

AFAIK, there are no other practical options.

Comment: cannot change the database column type

Comment: byte[] benMessage = enMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
                String cipherText = Base64.encodeBase64String(benMessage);  // encode
                System.out.println("Encrypted Message UTF-8: "+cipherText);   just did this, the output is ok but..its greater than the original string and i can´t have that

Comment: @Reversed - You have an impossible set of requirements.  The only solution is to change one of the requirements.